# Magento 2 : How to customise admin sales order grid collection?

Tags: magento2

I am trying to customise the admin sale order grid collection.
I have created an custom `sale_order` attribute `store_manager`. These store managers are the admin users eg: 'manager1', 'manager2'.

1) Orders are manually assigned to 'manager1' or 'manager2' -- **this part is done**

2) Now I am trying to set filter on sale order grid collection, so when manager logged in to there system they can only see there orders.

In Magento 1 we have `sales_order_grid_collection_load_before`, `sales_order_grid_collection_load_after` for this requirement .

Is tried to such event for Magento 2 but didn't get any success.

**My Queries :**

Is there any such event like (`sales_order_grid_collection_load_after`) in magento 1 which full fill my requirement?

Is there any other way where I can set filter to sale order grid collection?

Note : I already search for this on google but didn't get any perfect solution.

Comment: Any Solution about filter Order grid collection by admin user id?

Answer (score 5):

I was searching for the events `sales_order_grid_collection_load_after` and `sales_order_grid_collection_load_before` to customise the sales order grid.

My findings are, there are no such events in Magento 2. A general event `core_collection_abstract_load_after` or `core_collection_abstract_load_before` dispatch to render all of the grids in Magento 2 Admin.

We can override `_renderFiltersBefore()` function to add a column in sales order grid or to join table with `sales_order_grid`. Here are the steps:

**Step 1:** Specify class for sales order grid data source in `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sales_order_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Step 2:** Add a Collection class in `app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid.php` to override `_renderFiltersBefore()`

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OriginalCollection;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

class Collection extends OriginalCollection
{
    protected $_authSession;

    public function __construct(
       EntityFactory $entityFactory,
       Logger $logger,
       FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
       EventManager $eventManager,
       \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
    ) {        
       $this->_authSession = $authSession;
       parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager);
    }

    protected function _renderFiltersBefore() 
    {
        $user = $this->_authSession->getUser();
        $joinTable = $this->getTable('your_table');
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft($joinTable, 'main_table.entity_id = your_table.order_id', ['user_id']);
        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }
}
```

**Step 3 - Optional:** To show a new column of user id in Sales order grid, modify standard grid component in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="user_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">User ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

A reference is [here](https://magenable.com.au/magento-ecommerce/modifying-default-magento-2-sales-order-grid-adding-coupon-code-column/)

Comment: I place the di.xml in etc/di.xml but it's not working

Comment: @senthil you can check my recent answer.

Comment: for my case, I have added a column in sales_order_grid table with the name of "assigned_user", the super-admin assign particular orders to sub-admin.
while sub-admin login he can able to see only the assigned orders instead of all orders my query as follows $user = $this->_authSession->getUser();  if($user['user_id']!=1) {$this->addFieldToFilter('assigned_user_id', array(                     array('finset' =>$user['user_id']),))->getSelect(); }parent::_renderFiltersBefore(); , but its not working in etc/di.xml working only in etc/adminhtml/etc.xml but show error,so  i want it on etc/di.xml

Comment: Any Solution about filter Order grid collection by admin user id?

Comment: @senthil, etc/di.xml is the correct path. You should investigate if your files are not reached at all or there is some code at any line. 
I told you that we need to run some commands to clear cache etc. Commands are shared in new answer of this thread.

Comment: @senthil any solution?

Comment: How to reset applied filter on grid?

Answer (score 2):

We usually need to execute these commands after any `di.xml` changes:

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G /[MAGENTO2_ROOT]/bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -f /[MAGENTO2_ROOT]/bin/magento setup:upgrade
rm -rf /[MAGENTO2_ROOT]/var/view_preprocessed/ /[MAGENTO2_ROOT]/var/cache/ /[MAGENTO2_ROOT]/var/page_cache/ /[MAGENTO2_ROOT]/var/generation/
rm -rf  /[MAGENTO2_ROOT]/pub/static/frontend/
php -dmemory_limit=6G /[MAGENTO2_ROOT]/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php -f /[MAGENTO2_ROOT]/bin/magento cache:flush
php -f /[MAGENTO2_ROOT]/bin/magento cache:clean
sudo chmod -R 777 /[MAGENTO2_ROOT]/var /[MAGENTO2_ROOT]/pub
```

Use these as per your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

For our customized Grid, we’ll change the default data source with our own. Its parent is the standard class of the grid collection, which will let the third-party extensions effortlessly process modifications (if needed) using observers and plugins.

To implement that, in the di.xml file of our module, specify that another class should be used for the `sales_order_grid` data source.

> app/code/Vendor/ExtendGrid/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sales_order_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\ExtendGrid\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

As you can see, we’ll need an extension class for the collection. Let’s create it here:

> app/code/Vendor/ExtendGrid/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ExtendGrid\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OriginalCollection;
use Vendor\ExtendGrid\Helper\Data as Helper;

/**
* Order grid extended collection
*/
class Collection extends OriginalCollection
{
}
```

We modify the method `_renderFiltersBefore` so that it could connect to our table and select the necessary column there.

To do that,

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ExtendGrid\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OriginalCollection;
use Vendor\ExtendGrid\Helper\Data as Helper;

/**
* Order grid extended collection
*/
class Collection extends OriginalCollection
{
    protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
    {
        $joinTable = $this->getTable('sales_order');
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft($joinTable, 'main_table.entity_id = sales_order.entity_id', ['coupon_code']);
        //or filter in sale_order_grid collection then use like that
        $this->getSelect()->where("main_table.your_attribute is NULL");
        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be late but below is working and tested solution with Magento-2.3 for adding any filter to sales order grid.

Step 1: override `Magento/Sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml` to `Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml` and update dataProvider class(in overriden sales_order_grid.xml file) with your custom class say `Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/DataProvider/MyDataProvider.php`.

Step 2: Add following code to it

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\DataProvider;

use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\ReportingInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class MyDataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
{

    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        ReportingInterface $reporting,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        RequestInterface $request,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $reporting, $searchCriteriaBuilder, $request, $filterBuilder, $meta, $data);
        $this->myDefaultFilter();
    }

    protected function myDefaultFilter()
    {
        //do your stuff here get admin user id and apply filter accordingly

        //here is sample filtering
        $this->addFilter(
            $this->filterBuilder->setField('my_column_name')->setValue('value_to_be_filtered')->setConditionType('eq')->create()
        );
    }
    
}
```

Now in this `myDefaultFilter` function call your block to get current user detail and add logic accordingly to filter grid data.